# Relation between Hamming distances of columns and rows

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory

You're given a $0-1$ $n\times n$ matrix such that for every distinct columns $C_i$ and $C_j$, $d_H(C_i,C_j)\gt 2t$ for some $t$. What could be said about the Hamming distances of the rows? It it true for instance that there are two distinct rows $R_k$ and $R_l$ that satisfy $d_H(R_k,R_l)\lt n-t$?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried special cases such as $t = 0$?

Comment: Cross-posted on cstheory.se: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34152/relation-between-hamming-distances-of-0-1-matrix-columns-and-rows.

Answer (score 1):

The condition on the columns implies that $2t < n$. Suppose that the condition on the rows is not satisfied. The rows therefore form a code of minimal distance at least $n-t > n/2$ of size $n$. The [Plotkin bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotkin_bound) implies that unless $n-t$ is extremely close to $n/2$, such a code cannot exist. If $t$ is very close to $n/2$, however, the columns form a code of minimal distance close to $n$, which is again ruled out by the Plotkin bound (except perhaps for very small $n$).

I'll let you fill up the details and check for which $n$ this argument works.